# JUnit: The method is undefined for the type ParameterizedMethodTest

Tags: java, junit

My test is required to tested with multiple data records rather than single record at a time. `JUnitParamsRunner` is found for my requirement and trying to learn how it works. Following is my test class.

```
package test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import junitparams.Parameters;

@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class ParameterizedMethodTest {

    @Test
    @Parameters(method = "getAddedNumbers")
    public void test(int expect,int firstVal,int secondVal) {
        assertEquals("ex: "+expect+"  act: "+firstVal,expect, multiply(firstVal,secondVal) );
    }

    public Collection<Integer[]> getAddedNumbers(){
     return $( $(1, 1, 1)// compile error under the second $ sign
             , $(21, 11, 1)// compile error under the second $ sign
     );

    }

    private int multiply(int a,int b){
        return a*b;
    }

}
```

This has compile errors and couldn't figure out why. Error:

```
The method $(int, int, int) is undefined for the type ParameterizedMethodTest
```

Please let me know where this code has gone wrong?

Comment: Why do you think this should compile? Where is the `$()` method defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` is a [static method of JUnitParamsRunner](https://junitparams.googlecode.com/hg/apidocs/junitparams/JUnitParamsRunner.html#$%28java.lang.Object...%29).

So, to be able to use it, just like any static method, you need to use

```
JUnitParamsRunner.$(...);
```

Or you need to statically import the method to be able to use it without prepending the class name:

```
import static junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner.$;
```

But this method doesn't return an a `Integer[]` or a `Collection<Integer[]>`. It returns an `Object[]`. So your method signature must be changed, just as [the documentation examples](https://junitparams.googlecode.com/hg/apidocs/junitparams/JUnitParamsRunner.html) show, to

```
public Object[] getAddedNumbers()
```

Comment: Thanks JB for your clarification and the reference. I have a lot to get from it..